# height working inline but not external css

Tags: html, css

In the botton of this  there is a fullwidth picture with some stairs. I would like to make that around a 500px height.

It works when I set an inline height:

```
   <section class="pv-40 ding-bottom-clear parallax dark-translucent-bg hovered background-img-4">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="testimonial" style="height: 500px;">

                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </section>
```

But when I set the height in css it is not working, and I cannot understand why?

```
<div class="testimonial controlHeight">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.controlHeight {
   height: 500px;
}
```

It is a CSS document with a lot of lines CSS codes, so the document is called. I thought maybe something was overwriting, so I tried to set it at the end of the CSS document, but still not called.

Comment: Try to set important to height: 500px in colorHeight class.Probably you have some rule that is "stronger" than this one.

Comment: you dont need to use camel case in css styles

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I just tried to set `.controlHeight {
  height: 1000px !important;
}` but without result.

Comment: Are you sure, that your div has the right class definition? `class="testimonial controlHeight"`. In your website link the class definition is `class="testimonial test"`. You noticed that? In that case it has to be the following css rule `.testimonial.test{height:500px;}`.

Comment: I can see that my host is a little bit slow updating my site. The test was the very first thing I tried, but the correct class is there now. I just do not understand when I have !important why the class is not called. Could it be some SASS or LESS there is controling something?

Comment: Now it works fine.

Comment: where is it working?

Comment: http://roulettesuite.com/erhvervserfaring.php

Comment: wtf.. Chrome was caching so bad. I can see it is working now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
controlHeight {
   height: 500px;
}
```

Which matches against elements named `controlHeight`. You want:

```
.controlHeight {
   height: 500px;
}
```

which matches elements with the class `controlHeight`.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. The .controlHeight is in my CSS, I just did not copy here to Stackoverflow by a mistake.

Comment: Then there must be something overwriting the CSS? I tried to set the `  height: 1000px !important;` , but still not works.

Comment: @NeKr If the issue is caused by something outside of the code you've provided, you'll need to provide that additional code in order for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: I do not know if it is something from outside, but I am starting to think that. It should work. Could it be some SASS or LESS there is controling this?

Comment: @NeKr I took a look at your site and it is that element that is controlling the height there. Your `height: 1000px !important` is indeed working.

Comment: I found out that my chrome are caching, so I can see that it is solved now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`controlHeight` is a class selector. Therefore you need to write

```
.controlHeight {
   height: 500px;
}
```

**with the dot** at the beginning.

Comment: Thanky ou for the answer. Shoot my mistake. The dot was there, I just did not copy the dot here to Stackoverflow.